# Specification of lambda's return value doesn't work

Tags: c++, recursion, lambda, return-value, auto

I've got a problem.
The funciton "`__sub`" parses a string like `"1x + (5y - 2)"`. Each time it sees "`(`", it calls itself to parse exactly what is in parenthesis.
Here is some pseudocode, illustrating the problem:

```
auto __sub = [&needed_fn](const char *& iter, char end_at) -> int {
  for (; *iter != end_at; iter++) {
    if () {
      int number = needed_fn(iter);
    } else if (*iter == '(') {
      int sub_result = __sub(iter, ')');
    }
  }
  return 0; // temporarily, as for debugging purposes only needed
};
```

But this doesn't work. At first there was no specification of (`-> int`). 
And it doesn't work in both cases with or without that specification of the return value.

It says:

```
a.cpp: In lambda function:
a.cpp:97:22: error: use of ‘__sub’ before deduction of ‘auto’
 int sub_result = __sub(it, ')');
```

Comment: Is there a real value in using lambda expression? This looks like writing a regular function (taking needed_fn as an argument) would be simpler. Also, unless your actual code is significantly different, you're going to iterate beyond the buffer end if you don't find expected character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: define `__sub` as a `std::function<int(const char *, char)>`

```
std::function<int(const char * &, char)> __sub;

__sub = [&needed_fn](const char *& iter, char end_at) -> int {
  for (; *iter != end_at; iter++) {
    if ( /* ??? */ ) {
      int number = needed_fn(iter);
    } else if (*iter == '(') {
      int sub_result = __sub(iter, ')');
    }
  return 0;
};
```

otherwise the compiler can't deduce (`auto`) the type of `__sub()` using the same `__sub()` inside the body of `__sub()`.

Comment: What about the "if()" ?

Comment: "if" doesn't play the role there.
`std::function<int (const char *&, char)> __sub;
 __sub = [&needed_fn, &__sub]...`
worked

Comment: But **why** didn't it work my way even when I specified the return value explicitly?

Comment: @ЮрийСтражнов - isn't a problem of return type but simply a problem of type of `__sub()`; a sort of chicken-and-egg problem: every lambda has it's specific type; but if you define `auto` a lambda and use it inside it's body, you force the compiler to use the type of `__sub()` to decide the type of `__sub()`. If you say that `__sub` is a `std::function`, you avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to disagree with the assertion that it is a chicken and egg problem, or it is at least a solvable one, and suggest instead that this is a quirk of the language, because you can accomplish virtually the same thing by hand.

To slightly simplify the discussion, take a common recursive example, factorial ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/l4cEtt)):

```
auto factorial = [](int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
```

It fails with the error you see:

```
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:7:24: error: use of 'factorial' before deduction of 'auto'
    7 |             return n * factorial(n-1);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
```

But `factorial` is a variable of automatic storage duration, so you cannot refer to it without capturing it, and the code must be **incorrect** without a capture. Capturing by value doesn't make sense, as the lambda type would contain a copy of itself. That would be inconsistent with typical C++ classes which cannot contain copies of themselves, even if otherwise empty. Thus, one must capture by reference ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/kBRr3o)):

```
auto factorial = [&factorial](int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
```

Our code is now more correct.  What does the compiler say?

```
<source>:3:24: error: use of 'factorial' before deduction of 'auto'
    3 |     auto factorial = [&factorial](int n) {
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
<source>: In lambda function:
<source>:7:24: error: use of 'factorial' before deduction of 'auto'
    7 |             return n * factorial(n - 1);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~
```

More errors! A lambda is just syntactic sugar for a function object, so let's take a step back and see if the unsugared form would just work ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ns4lWS)):

```
struct factorial_t
{
    factorial_t& factorial;
    auto operator()(int n) const
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    factorial_t factorial{factorial};
}
```

That works, and in a perfect world, maybe the lambda form would too. Before the `auto` in `factorial` is deduced, it is very much *like* an incomplete type. References and pointers to incomplete types are allowed in C++ including those to a class or struct which contains them. And lambda reference captures are just references or pointers. So this is all possible within the spirit of the language. A different language could deduce the type of `factorial` to the type of the lambda, while the lambda type is incomplete, i.e. before attempting to create a definition for the lambda type.

In C++, you have a few possible solutions. First, you can write the closure type by hand (as in [the third example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ns4lWS)).

Second, you can erase the type, as in the other answer ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c1gmqs)):

```
std::function<int(int)> factorial = [&factorial](int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
};
```

Note that the other answer was missing the capture which is key.

Third, you can delay the need for the type ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/g8VNOs)):

```
auto factorial = [](int n, auto&& factorial) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1, factorial);
};
```

That delays the need for the type by making the call operator a template, at the cost of an awkward usage, e.g. `factorial(4, factorial)`. Even that is surmountable with a small level of indirection ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6Y1GFh)):

```
auto factorial_impl = [](int n, auto&& factorial_impl) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial_impl(n - 1, factorial_impl);
};

auto factorial = [&factorial_impl](int n) {
    return factorial_impl(n, factorial_impl);
};
```

Hope this helps!